# How to place button in window on bottom left in pysimplegui

Tags: python

I am new to `pysimplegui` and want to place a button on the bottom left of a window. Exact placement is not a concern.
My code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#create window layout
layout = [
          [sg.Text("How many random numbers to generate?"),sg.InputText(key="-USERVALUE-")],
          [sg.Button("Generate and Save"),sg.Button("Read and Display")],
           [sg.Button("Exit")],
          ]

window =sg.Window("Random Numbers",layout,size=(640, 320))
while True:
# create dictionary of window values
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event  == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
window.close
```

I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Comment: What happened when you ran the code? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Add one row with helper gunction `VPush()` before your last button row.